# jQuery Access Object Property with compound name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access jQuery's `.text()` method on a dynamically generated page element, meaning the `id` is of the form `bBtn_123` where the integer after the underscore represents a unique id. So, I'd like to be able to call `bBtn_123` (or whatever the id happens to be) in the success callback (deprecated, I know), of my Ajax call. Here's how I'm trying to access it:

```
('#bBtn_' + spId).text()
```

I'm sure there's some way of doing this, but I'm getting a type error on this, reporting to me that `.text()` is not a function.

Here's the rest of my function for some perspective:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="bBtn_"]', function() {
var spId = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
$.ajax({
    url: '/bookmark/' + spId,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
        if (('#bBtn_' + spId).text() == "Bookmark") {
            (('#bBtn_' + spId).text("Bookmarked!"))
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
});
});
```

Edit: Apologies for the title, if it's not particularly great,  I wasn't sure quite what to go with.

Comment: its a typo nothing just add $ before the compound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the $ symbol. It should be like:

```
$('#bBtn_' + spId).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `$`: `$('#bBtn_' + spId).text()`

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the $ symbol.

$('#bBtn_' + spId).text()

Answer (score 0):

Change those lines:

```
if (('#bBtn_' + spId).text() == "Bookmark") {
    (('#bBtn_' + spId).text("Bookmarked!"))
}
```

By:

```
var id = '#bBtn_' + spId;
if($(id).text() === "Bookmark") {
    $(id).text("Bookmarked!");
}
```